# How to provide updates for a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

What i can do is a curl request to my server where i will have the code for every release and check those every time a admin logs in to the system.
But is there a better way or documentation oh how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an open plugin? That just use the WordPress repo with SVN. Else I would recommend to publish your plugin to a (private) GitHub repo and use a tool like GitHub updater https://github.com/afragen/github-updater for your code deployment.

Comment: Thanks Niels. 
Its not an open plugin. Its gonna be a premium one

Comment: At this link you can find some sample codes (a bit old, but it will give you a good idea how) for a self hosted update service. http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/daily-tip-offer-automatic-updates-for-plugins-and-themes-hosted-outside-wordpress-extend/

Comment: Super Niels. Top link